# Create a column and add rows from an inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

i've two tables ones employes_tbl and second one deparments i get the firstName from the inner join of them , i did this so i can get the name of the responsable based on the department name
here is the query im using :

```
 ALTER TABLE employes_tbl ADD responsable_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ;

 UPDATE employes_tbl SET responsable_name = (SELECT departments.firstName FROM departments INNER JOIN employes_tbl  WHERE  departments.departement =  employes_tbl.departement)
```

how ever i try to append them to a column it returns an error :

ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: Why would you want to store the name of the *responsable* in every row of the employees table?

Comment: i'm filling an HTML from that data

Comment: also to get the name of the responsable based on what department they are for example , if you belong to IT deparment your responsable name will be JACK

Comment: You can do this with a SELECT query where you join the tables. What will you do if the *responsable* in a department changes? Will you update the table employees again?

Comment: Yes it will update the employees again if the responsable changes

Comment: This is exactly what yo should avoid when designing a database. Take some time to read about database normalization: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: thank you ! after i readed that i concluded that i don't need to insert a new column i can just do this instead and it satisfied my needs here ; to fill my html table however i like : ``` SELECT departments.firstName as responsable_name FROM departments INNER JOIN employes_tbl  ON departments.departement = employes_tbl.departement ```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple employees per department, so oyu need `DISTINCT` the firname, to get only one name

```
 UPDATE employes_tbl 
SET 
    responsable_name = (SELECT 
           DISTINCT  departments.firstName
        FROM
            departments
                INNER JOIN
            employes_tbl
        WHERE
            departments.departement = employes_tbl.departement
        )
```

Comment: it sill returning ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row , i dont want one name i want to get the name of the responsable based on what deparment the employe belongs to

Comment: can you provide a fiddle with your data please, maybe departments.departement  is not unique and you get may firstnames, then you should urgently normalize your database